# A better, concise way to express the "school year period"?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request, expressions

From late August to June, this is the period when the school year runs, is there any better and shorter way to express this than to say "school year"?

For example, a company that wants to say that they work in synchrony with the period from August to June and then don't take up or do work from mid-June to mid-August might not want to say something like,

> We take projects throughout the *school year*

because the expression *school* is out of context and sounds quite bad.

Answer (score 1):

> We accept projects throughout the year excluding **summer vacation**. (i.e. 15th June to 15th August)

In other words, the company takes a longish summer break, it closes from mid-June to mid-August.

Answer (score 0):

Although not exactly a shorter way to say that, have you considered using the term [**the academic year**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/academic_year)? The following definition is from the English Oxford Living Dictionaries:

> the period of the year during which students attend school or university, usually reckoned from the beginning of the autumn term to the end of the summer term.

Examples:

> In the United States, **the academic year** starts in September.
>
> We take projects throughout **the entire academic year**.

But you have to understand that when you say *academic year*, it implies that what you're talking about is somehow connected to the idea that younger people are going to be studying during this period. If what you're talking about has nothing to do with schooling and going to the university whatsoever, then it would probably be better to just explicitly say when exactly your company begins taking projects and when that stops.